# Physical inituition for axial and vector form factors of a hadron

Tags: particle-physics

I often see a decomposition of the matrix element $\langle V|\bar{q}\Gamma^{\mu} Q |P\rangle$, where $V$ is a vector particle, for example a vector meson or a photon, $P$ is a pseudoscalar meson, and $\Gamma ^{\mu}$ is arbitrary, for example $\gamma ^{\mu}(1-\gamma _5)$. For example, the matrix can be decomposed as 
$$\langle \gamma |\bar{q}\Gamma Q |P\rangle=\epsilon _{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\varepsilon ^{\nu}p_P^{\rho}p_{\gamma}^{\sigma}\times F_V+i\left(\varepsilon ^{\mu}p_P\cdot p_{\gamma}-p_{\gamma}^{\mu}\varepsilon \cdot p_P\right)\times F_A$$ 
where $F_V$ and $F_A$ are vector and axial form factors, respectively.

My question is, what is the physical meaning or intuition for $F_V$ and $F_A$? For example, what would $F_A=0$ or $F_V=0$ imply?  Or what would $Im(F_A) \neq 0$ or $Im(F_V) \neq 0$ imply? Any hint would be helpful, thanks very much!